# How to get JSON from Android and insert it into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am very new to using PHP and MySQL so I am looking for some much needed guidance.

What I am attempting to do, is read a JSON array that is sent from an Android application, and then insert that information into a MySQL database. I understand that this isn't very specific, but if anyone could provide/walk me through a generalized PHP script that could accomplish this task, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first you will need to read up on [PHP and JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php), more specifically the [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

That transforms your json variable into a PHP variable.

Then you'll want to read up on [PHP and MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), so you can insert that variable in MySQL. Usually you [first prepare, then execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) a statement.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to decode the JSON to PHP array

```
$android_data = json_decode($json, true);
```

and then create the mySQL query:

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET name = '".$android_data['name']."'")) {
    echo "data was inserted successfully";
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

you can check the documentation here:

- [json_decode](http://bg.php.net/json_decode)
- [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)
- [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)